# Getting the position of a picture in 8086 assembler

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Is there a way to get the position of a picture in 8086 assembler? 
(In graphics mode)

Background:
What I'm trying to do is a game that an arrow revolves around a picture(the player), when the user presses <kbd>space</kbd> the picture moves (At the same direction the arrow points at) and will stop when the user enters <kbd>space</kbd> again and so forth.

But I'm stuck. I don't know how to draw the arrows after the picture moves from its initial position...

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to "get the position" ... you have drawn it, you know where it is?

Comment: its moving... I need to draw the arrows each time the picture changes position

Comment: You know where everything is.

Comment: I don't know. the game needs to do it automatically. The user only presses space to move the player and then another space to stop the player in place. The picture can be anywhere on the screen.

Comment: You are drawing the picture, you know where it is. The picture won't move by itself, only if you draw it again and again (presumably from a timer or something). Thus, you know where you have last drawn it.

Comment: I mean where the picture is on the screen (x,y) coordinates
because when the picture lets say moved 30 pixels up. I need to draw the arrows that revolve around the picture: the arrow that points upwards 
(the same x as the picture, and the same y of the picture **+5 pixels**) for space between the picture and the arrow. Because I don't want to draw the arrow picture on the player.

Comment: there's a video that represents the same idea as the game but it's in text mode. imagine that the asterisk  is the arrow and the '0' as the main picture (the player)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsdtfHYneHY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the position of a picture in 8086 assembler? (In graphics mode)

Sure, just read the associated variables that record the position of the picture.

```
PositionX dw 0
PositionY dw 0
```

You also need to keep track of the position of the arrow (surely you do this already!):

```
ArrowX dw 0
ArrowY dw 0
```

### How it works.

At the arrival of the 1st  <kbd>space</kbd>  you copy these positional values to some *Temp* locations

```
mov  ax, [PositionX]
mov  [TempX], ax
mov  ax, [PositionY]
mov  [TempY], ax
```

Now you let the game (automatically) move the picture in the direction that the arrow is pointing. Each time the game redraws the picture, it will also update the associated variables *PositionX* and *PositionY*. You just sit back and watch the picture move.

At the arrival of the 2nd  <kbd>space</kbd>  you calculate the difference between both sets of variables.
If the arrow was pointing upward you **know** that *PositionY* will be smaller than *TempY* (because that's how the Y coordinates work on the screen) and that *PositionX* will be equal to *TempX*. This means:

```
mov  ax, [PositionY]
sub  ax, [TempY]
mov  [DeltaY], ax    ;With UP, this will be a negative number
mov  [DeltaX], 0
```

Think about how this logic varies for the other 3 possible directions.

Now the real beauty is that you don't even need to reflect on the possible outcome for these different directions! Just use the following:

```
mov  ax, [PositionX]
sub  ax, [TempX]
mov  [DeltaX], ax
mov  ax, [PositionY]
sub  ax, [TempY]
mov  [DeltaY], ax
```

Finally to draw the arrow at the new spot, you first erase it from where it is currently (using the current contents of the *ArrowX* and *ArrowY* variables) and then redraw it at its new location by adding the *DeltaX* and *DeltaY* variables to the maching *ArrowX* and *ArrowY* variables:

```
mov  [Color], 0    ;Black
call DrawArrow     ;Erase arrow
mov  ax, [DeltaX]
add  [ArrowX], ax
mov  ax, [DeltaY]
add  [ArrowY], ax
mov  [Color], 15   ;White
call DrawArrow     ;Show arrow
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! 
I found a way that is similar to yours